# Start 2010 workflow from 2013 and Impersonation / Permissions

Tags: 2013, 2010, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a 2013 workflow that kicks off a start 2010 workflow. The workflow it launches has a manual start. It uses impersonation, and it changes the items permission. If I run the 2010 flow manually it works. If I run it launching from the 2013 it starts then fails at the point of changing the permissions. Why would this happen? I am not passing a parameter in the start 2010 workflow, should I pass the ID or something?